# PHPBB 3.0.1 website migrating to new hosting service

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I am trying to find some guidance on where to go next on the issue I am having migrating a phpbb3 site from one hosting service to another.

I have checked to make sure the config.php file has been changed to work on the new server, as well as the common.php file. I am getting a HTTP 500 error when I try to search for the forum. The main site is working normally, just the message board is having a problem.

Nothing about the structure of the sites pages has changed, only the hosting server. (I downloaded a copy of the website before moving it so I have everything in the exact way it was before, just on the new server.)

Do I need to install phpbb onto the server itself with Softaculous?

Anything would help, I need to get the site back up and running soon.

Thanks in advance.
Jacob

Comment: If there is an error 500 thrown, what does your server's error log tell you about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php version on the new hosting services server was above what phpBB 3.0.x needed. I upgraded phpBB to version 3.2.9 and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

This post would have been better addressed on phpBB.com support section...
In any cases most hosting companies out there will perform the migration for you for free.

Did you ask about handling a migration for you?

There are many things that need to be done when migrating to a new hosting. 
here a couple of pointers for you:

-PHP version in use should be PHP 5.6.x as phpBB 3.0.x does not support higher PHP versions

-config.php might need updating, for example these two fields:

```
$dbhost = '';
$dbport = '';
```

-check your error logs in your cPanel as they will reveal the cause of the 500 error

Also, NO you do not need Softaculous

I'll be happy to help you with this if you PM me on:
https://www.phpbb.com/community/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=1428301

-SiteSplat

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was able to get it working by upgrading to a newer version of phpBB. Looks like the php version was incapable.